# Homotopy between circle and semi-circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, homotopy-theory

It is easy to see that a circle and a semi-circle (as in the image), of the same radius, are homotopic. I was trying to exhibit a homotopy, but it seems that I'll have to use analytic geometry, solve second degree equations, etc, in the way. I am lazy and I do not want to do that, if it can be avoided.

[image]

> Is there an intelligent way of doing this?

**Context:** I want to prove that if $R > 1$, then the index of $\gamma: [0, 2\pi] \to \Bbb C$ given by $\gamma(t) = Re^{it}$ if $0 \leq t \leq \pi$, and $\gamma(t) = \frac{2R}{\pi}(t-\pi)-R$ if $\pi \leq t \leq 2\pi$ with respect to $i$ is $1$. I can use that a homotopy preserves the index, and if a point $\alpha$ has absolute value less than $R$, then ${\rm Ind}(\sigma, \alpha) = 1$, if $\sigma(t) = Re^{it}$, $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$.

Comment: Do you mean the disk and the semi-disk? Because a semi-circle is retractable, while a circle is not.

Comment: I am thinking of curves only, here. By retractable you mean homotopic to a point?

Comment: So, by semicircle, you mean including the arc of the diameter?

Comment: Yes, what's in red plus the segment joining $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$. (English is not my first language, sorry if I caused some confusion)

Comment: Radial projection taking the point $(0, 0.5)$ as the centre point gives a homeomorphism between the two spaces. What more do you need?

Comment: In fact I wanted to build the homotopy $H(s,t)$ between the curves, avoiding all the work of analytic geometry and such. Actually, seeing a radial projection is what convinced me that the sets are homotopic. Well, I'm thinking that there isn't a smart way to come up with the explicit $H$ without doing the computations. Bummer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a straight line homotopy,
$$
(t,(x,y))\mapsto
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
(x,t\sqrt{1-x^2})&y\geq0\\
(x,y)&y<0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
between the two maps $S^1\to\mathbb{R}^2$.